# WebDriverException ao não encontrar elementos com FIndElements

Tags: c#, testes, selenium-webdriver

Quando tento verificar se um elemento existe ou não na minha página web e caso o elemento não exista, o meu IWebDriver lança uma *WebDriverException*, e todos os métodos do meu driver deixam de funcionar, impossibilitando que eu continue com a execução do teste mesmo fazendo o tratamento para retornar null ou 0 em um catch.

Gostaria de lembrar o método de verificaçlão que estou utilizando está na documentação do Selenium, dizendo para usar o FindElements ao invés de FindElement: `findElement should not be used to look for non-present elements, use WebDriver.findElements(By) and assert zero length response instead.`

Estou usando a versão mais recente do Selenium WebDriver e do ChromeDriver para C#.

Erro informado na Exception:
    [OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException]

```
The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:18144/session/5eeb22629a0d6f35b829113728c3f5a7/elements timed out after 60 seconds.`
```

Método que utilizo para verificar se elemento existe ou não:

```
public IWebElement SafeFindElement(By by)
{
    try
    {
        var element = _driver.FindElements(by);
        return element.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei descobrindo o problema, então vou compartilhar caso aconteça com alguém. Aconteceu em um método que eu chamo muitas vezes na suíte de testes, onde ele verifica se a página está carregando (e exibindo um modal de loading)e espera até que não esteja mais. Isso é necessário para que o modal não influencie nos testes.

Porém, a página que eu tentava fazer essa verificação não tinha jquery, era apenas uma página com um corpo em html e css exibindo um certificado, aí caía na exeption que vocês podem ver abaixo n vezes até completar um intervalo de 1 minuto acontecendo isso, e depois caía na exception com um erro diferente de `$ is not defined`, aí saía do método e, a partir disso, FindElements quebrava o selenium sempre que tentava retornar uma lista com 0 elementos.

O método que causou isso, sem o tratamento do erro:

```
public void WaitLoadingMessage(int tempoRestanteLoading)
{
    while (tempoRestanteLoading > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            var loadingIsVisible = _js.ExecuteScript("return $('#loading-geral').is(':visible');").ToString();

            if (loadingIsVisible.ToLower() == "false")
                break;

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            tempoRestanteLoading -= 1000;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (!ex.Message.ToLower().Contains("$ is not defined"))
                throw;
        }
    }
}
```

A correção encontrada para o método:

```
public void WaitLoadingMessage(int tempoRestanteLoading)
{
    while (tempoRestanteLoading > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            var loadingIsVisible = _js.ExecuteScript("return $('#loading-geral').is(':visible');").ToString();

            if (loadingIsVisible.ToLower() == "false")
                break;

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            tempoRestanteLoading -= 1000;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (!ex.Message.ToLower().Contains("$ is not defined"))
                throw;

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            tempoRestanteLoading -= 1000;
        }
    }
}
```